# Serverless command "resources" not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, apigee, serverless

I am trying to deploy a serverless application in aws and using that via API Gateway (apigee in my case). While I am running "sls resources deploy", It shows error like this:[Image showing the error output from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV0bf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `sls deploy` (without `resources`).